# Use a loop and render multiple jsx items later return to render

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to find a smarter way to loop through an array and generate jsx and return to the render function:

```
  renderCardImages = () => {
    const cards = [
      'Visa',
      'MasterCard',
      'AmericanExpress',
      'Discover',
      'JCB',
    ]
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <Image source={getCardIcon('Visa')} size={65} />
        <Image source={getCardIcon('MasterCard')} size={65} />
        <Image source={getCardIcon('AmericanExpress')} size={65} />
        <Image source={getCardIcon('Discover')} size={65} />
        <Image source={getCardIcon('JCB')} size={65} />
      </View>
    )
  }

  render () {

    return (
     {renderCardImages()}
    )
  }
```

How do I achieve this? I believe render is called only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return (
  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
    {card.map(c=>((<Image source={getCardIcon(c)} size={65} />))}
  </View>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the list of cards outside of the component if it's static, or get it from props if it's dynamic. Use `Array.map()` in the render function to iterate the list, and render the cards:

```
render () {
  return (
   <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      {cars.map(card => (
        <Image source={getCardIcon(card)} size={65} />        
      ))}
   </View>
  )
}
```